# Are there any drawbacks in moving login logic out of the 'signIn()' method of NextAuth.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I am using NextAuth.js for the first time and I find that signing in using the Credentials provider is a bit complicated when it comes to handling errors. From what I understand, the default implementation should look like:

```
// app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

export const authOptions = {
   ...
   providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
         name: 'credentials',
         credentials: {},
         async authorize( credentials ) {
            // Implement login logic and fetch the user
            if ( user ) {
               return user
            }
            return null
         }
      })
   ],
}

// LoginForm.js

async function login( data ) {

   // 'redirect' must be set to false,
   // so that signIn() returns a promise instead of redirecting

   const response = await signIn( 'credentials', {
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
      redirect: false
   })

   // If there was an error, it is returned under the promise's 'error' key

   if( response.error ) {
      // Handle the error. This is the tricky part I think, 
      // because if I want to throw a specific error in my login logic
      // I would have to stringify it over there and then parse it here etc. 
      // which is a mess especially for validation errors!
   }

}

export default function LoginForm() {
   return (
      <Form onSubmit={ data => login( data ) }>
         // Form here
      <Form>
   )
}
```

So I've tested a workaround that seems to work, which basically consists of moving the login logic out of `signIn()` and only invoke `signIn()` after login, by passing it the user object itself rather than the credentials. So here's what I would do:

```
WORKAROUND

// app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

export const authOptions = {
   ...
   providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
         name: 'credentials',
         credentials: {},
         async authorize( user ) {
            // No more login logic here! Just pass in the user directly
            if ( user ) {
               return user
            }
            return null
         }
      })
   ],
}

// LoginForm.js

async function login( data ) {

   // Move the login logic here!

   const user = await fetch( 'http://localhost:3000/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify( data )
   })

   // Handle any errors here
   // If all goes well, call signIn()

   await signIn( 'credentials', user )

   // Continue

}

export default function LoginForm() {
   return (
      <Form onSubmit={ data => login( data ) }>
         // Form here
      <Form>
   )
}
```

This seems to work, cookies and tokens are set successfully. I was wondering if there are any drawbacks though.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious drawback that comes to mind is that you are missing CSRF protection in this implementation.

IMO using custom error strings is not a high price to pay here. You can even use specific HTTP response codes to identify various error types. Just keep in mind there is currently a [bug](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7725) in NextAuth under the `app` router causing it to always return 200 OK (though there is a [workaround](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7638#issuecomment-1599319687)).

I hope this helps.